# Update ng-options when scope variable changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I have a selectbox with ng-options. When a http request updates the scope variable at controller it doesn't refresh on the UI(selectbox). Is it possible to get selectbox options refreshed?

My scenario, i load selectbox options from db(lookup collection) so there will be a situation where we need to add new value to lookup so i have a small link to add new value through popup. When new value is stored to db, i call angular service which updates scope variable with new values. Here, my select box options are not updated.

Answer (score 0):

try calling that function in $timeout because $timeout will call $apply and will update your data.

Comment: $timeout also not refreshing options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `$scope.$apply()`to manually trigger `$digest` cycle.